# How to set image when implementing global search for Android TV

Tags: android, android-tv

I'm implementing global search for Android TV based on this sample project https://github.com/googlesamples/androidtv-Leanback

I set poster image in Content Provider and associate it with field SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_RESULT_CARD_IMAGE. It always display this poster in landscape mode and with ugly quality. It looks same even when I run this sample project.

Any suggestions, how I should work with this field and force it to show card with image in poster mode?

I use AndroidTV emulator with API 21 to run my test project.

Answer (score 0):

What I found is that, the resolution of the first item that is shown i.e. Portrait 270x400, will dictate the resolution ratio of the rest of the items on that row.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).